# Do I need phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a very small personal website, written with HTML editor.  I have never used this feature and don't even know how, I don't have any wordpress blogs or anything written in PHP, do I need this?  For some strange reason, I actually have 4 of them....  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web application written in PHP that gives you a GUI in order to access a MySQL database. If you're not using it, you can delete it (though it's a useful tool).

Comment: You have 4 of them, what are you talking about?

Comment: For some reason, I have four.  They are all named something different like Myphpadmin, AdminPhP, etc.  It's possible that I installed all of these and renamed them, trying to obscure the file from hackers.  I have never used these files for anything.  I don't even know how. I don't use PHP, but at one time I did have four blogs, so maybe one for each?  Anyway, I'm going to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

If your site relies on pure, static HTML, you don't need phpMyAdmin or any other PHP files for that matter.

It **will** be safe to delete `phpMyAdmin` from your website as long as you don't update it using databases. If all changes you do are manual (hard-coded), feel free to delete all 4 of them.